# Query with subquery not returning all results

Tags: mysql, subquery

I am doing the next query:

```
SELECT id, name, keyt
FROM table
WHERE id = (SELECT t2.id FROM table t2 WHERE t2.keyt=21 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1)
```

**Supposing** table is like this:

```
| id |  name      |  keyt   |
+ ------------------------- +
| 1  |  Hello     |  21     |
| 3  |  Katzet    |  1      |
| 1  |  Welcome   |  1      |
| 2  |  Two       |  21     |
| 2  |  Other     |  1      |
```

It **should** return one of this pairs:

- Hello | Welcome (id **1** in common)
- Two | Other (id **2** in common)

**So, the idea is:**
Get one id, which has the `keyt` value set to 21
Then, get all the rows with this selected id *(independently of all the other keyt values)*

If I do as you suggested... I would get mixed **id** values, and all result rows must have the same **id**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT id 
         FROM my_table 
        WHERE keyt = 21 
        ORDER 
           BY RAND() LIMIT 1
     ) y 
    ON y.id = x.id;
```

Comment: Well, nice one. This is working great. But, may you please briefly explain to me why the other option was not accurate? Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

The subquery in this query

`SELECT id, name, keyt
FROM table
WHERE id = (SELECT t2.id FROM table t2 WHERE t2.keyt=21 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1)`

would return only one record as it has `LIMIT 1` added at the end.

> Also, in your question, the table contains only 1 record for which
>   value of **`keyt` = 21**, due to which you're getting only one record.

If you want more records, you should remove the `LIMIT`. In that case you may rephrase your query as:

`SELECT id, name, keyt
FROM table
WHERE id IN (SELECT t2.id FROM table t2 WHERE t2.keyt=21 ORDER BY RAND())`

Hope this is what you expected. As your actual goal is not very clear from the question.

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking your time. I think I didn't do a good example. I updated my question so you may understand better what I need. But, anyway.. why does the subquery LIMIT affect to the PRIMARY query? My idea is to get a random id, where I know it has the `keyt`=21, and then output all rows with this id :)

Comment: but a subquery must return only one result @ theghostofc

Comment: @Bhushan, it depends on the type of subquery. A subquery for a `WHERE` clause should return one result, but a subquery for an `IN` clause might return multiple results.

Answer (score 0):

Your table has two 21 in the keyt column so your subquery in the where clause returns 2 values if id that is 1 and 2.So what you need to do is instead of using an equal to operator "=" use IN operator in the where clause.

```
SELECT id, name, keyt FROM table WHERE id IN (SELECT t2.id FROM table t2 WHERE t2.keyt=21 ORDER BY RAND())
```